# How to write function with multiple grouping variable in R? I am using curly curly operator

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have written following function to calculate average of the desired columns after grouping by another variable.

```
calculate_avg <- function(df, of_colmn, by_var = NULL){

    df %>%
        group_by({{ by_var }}) %>% 
        summarise(across({{ of_colmn }}, list(avg = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE))))
}
```

This work perfectly fine if I keep zero or only one by_var but when I try to run it with more than one by_var, it produces error.

For example, when I run this code "mpg" dataset which has 234 rows, it produces following error:

```
Code : calculate_avg(mpg, c(cty, hwy, displ), c(class, trans))
```

```
Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = c(class, trans)`.
i `..1` must be size 234 or 1, not 468.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `across` in `group_by` -

```
library(dplyr)

calculate_avg <- function(df, of_colmn, by_var = NULL){
  
  df %>%
    group_by(across({{ by_var }})) %>% 
    summarise(across({{ of_colmn }}, list(avg = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE))))
}

calculate_avg(mpg, c(cty, hwy, displ), c(class, trans))

#  class   trans      cty_avg hwy_avg displ_avg
#   <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 2seater auto(l4)      15      23        5.7 
# 2 2seater auto(s6)      15      25        6.2 
# 3 2seater manual(m6)    15.7    25.3      6.3 
# 4 compact auto(av)      19.5    28.5      2.55
# 5 compact auto(l3)      24      30        1.8 
# 6 compact auto(l4)      20.2    27.9      2.25
# 7 compact auto(l5)      16.2    26.2      2.3 
# 8 compact auto(s4)      20      26        2.5 
# 9 compact auto(s5)      20      29        2.85
#10 compact auto(s6)      20.2    27.8      2.32
# … with 27 more rows
```

Comment: An alternative here (to save the input to the function needing `c()`) would be to use `...` to pass in the grouping variable(s). Only a minor difference here, as you're already providing the option to pass multiple variables to summarise across, but seemed worth mentioning.

(Reference: https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/multiple.html#simple-forwarding-of-...)